# Erro em INSERT INTO de string com Aspas

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho o INSERT INTO abaixo que apresenta erro no campo onde está o valor     
`'[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]'`

```
INSERT INTO ADVDEV."Mascara"("Guid", "MascaraId", "EmpresaId", 
"GrupoEmpresaId", "TarefaId", "Codigo", "Sigla", "Descricao", "Prefixo", 
"Sufixo", "SeparadorNiveis", "QuantidadeNiveis", "SiglaAdicionaGrava", 
"Sequencial", "MascaraFormatada", "MascaraExpression", "DataCadastro", 
"DataAlteracao", "DataInativacao", "UsuarioCadastroId", 
"UsuarioAlteracaoId", "UsuarioInativacaoId", "Excluido") VALUES(1, 1410, 333, 348, 75, '3', 'PES', 'Pessoa', NULL, NULL, '.', 1, 'GRAVA', 'S', '9999/9999', 
'[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'N');
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar a inserir esse campo de máscara ? Acredito que o erro pode estar no uso das aspas dentro de aspas:

[image]

Comment: Sim o erro está nesse '/' no meio do que seria uma string: '[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]', mas ele não está interpretando como uma única string já que o caractere ' fecha a string e / não é um separador de campos.

Comment: consegui resolver utilizando 2 aspas simples `'[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ''/'', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]'`